# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'stages' found among steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I got an error "*java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method stages found among steps*" when I run the script below.

Can someone tell me why and how I can solve the issue?

Basically I need to do foreach of my stage and it has to be run parallel. Can we do it on declarative pipeline?

```
def services = ["A", "B", "C"]
 
def parallelStagesMap = services.collectEntries {
    ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}

def generateStage(service) {
    return {
        stage("${service}") {
            agent { label 'dotnet-agent' }
            environment {
                PROJECT = "myProject.${service}"
                ARTIFACT_NAME = "${GIT_COMMIT}-${service}.zip"
            }
            stages {
                stage('Build-${service}') {
                    steps {
                        include 'automation/jenkins/${service}/buildAndArtifact'
                    }
                }

                stage('Test-${service}') {
                    steps {
                        dir("src/${PROJECT}.Tests") {
                            sh("dotnet test ${PROJECT}.Tests.csproj -c ${ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}")
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('Deploy-${service}') {
                    steps {
                        include 'automation/jenkins/${service}/deploy'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent { label 'dotnet-agent' }
    stages {
        stage('Set credentials') {
            stages {
                stage('Build') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                            parallel parallelStagesMap
                        }
                     }
                }           
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if you can have nested stages like you are trying to do.

This seems to work:

```
def services = ["A", "B", "C"]
 
def parallelStagesMap = services.collectEntries {
    ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}

def generateStage(service) {
    return {
        echo "build $service"
        echo "test $service"
        echo "deploy $service"
    }    
}

pipeline {
    agent any 
    environment {
        PROJECT = "myProject.${service}"
        ARTIFACT_NAME = "${GIT_COMMIT}-${service}.zip"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelStagesMap
                }
             }
        }   
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] { (Branch: A)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: B)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: C)
[Pipeline] echo
build A
[Pipeline] echo
test A
[Pipeline] echo
deploy A
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] echo
build B
[Pipeline] echo
test B
[Pipeline] echo
deploy B
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] echo
build C
[Pipeline] echo
test C
[Pipeline] echo
deploy C
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with something similar recently, and I came to a solution using some blend of scripted and declarative syntax. The problem I could not overcome with using purely declarative syntax, was to define agents dynamically.

So if you don't mind loosing some of the declarative benefits then I think your pipeline could maybe look something like this:

```
def services = ["A", "B", "C"]

def parallelStagesMap = services.collectEntries {
    ["${it}" : generateStage(it)]
}

def generateStage(service) {
    return {
        node('dotnet-agent') {
            withEnv(["PROJECT=myProject.${service}", "ARTIFACT_NAME=${GIT_COMMIT}-${service}.zip"]) {
                stage("${service}") {
                    stage('Build-${service}') {
                        include 'automation/jenkins/${service}/buildAndArtifact'
                    }
                    stage('Test-${service}') {
                        dir("src/${PROJECT}.Tests") {
                            sh("dotnet test ${PROJECT}.Tests.csproj -c ${ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT}")
                       }
                    }
                    stage('Deploy-${service}') {
                        include 'automation/jenkins/${service}/deploy'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

pipeline {
    agent { label 'dotnet-agent' }
    stages {
        stage('Generate stages') {
            steps {
                script {
                    parallel parallelStagesMap
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't had a chance to test this exact code, except for syntax, so I am not sure, but the idea should work.